# Elgamal encryption algorithm

Tags: asymmetric, algorithm

I have question about elgamal algorithm, Why NIST do not certified this algorithm, And every implementation of this algorithm in Python language have Vulnerability?

Comment: Do you have any examples of Python implementations that are known to be vulnerable? Are you asking *if* they are vulnerable, or *why* they are vulnerable?

Comment: The first part - why hasn't NIST certified this - should be answerable. I'm not sure if the second part of the question can be objectively answered. My best guess is that it's simply because... it's notoriously hard to implement a cryptographic algorithm so that it is secure.

Comment: HI. My first question is Why NIST not certified this algorithm?

Comment: Second question is this Algorithm in Python lib have Vulnerability ?